# Create a calculator for incentive date generation

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I am trying to create a calculator for incentive date generation. below is the scenario:

A salesmen will get incentives if a buyer purchases his product and he uses that product for  90 days(i.E 3 months) and that incentive will be credtited to Salesmen salray account on 15 th of the next month(after 90days)..

So I need a logic to to display the First Incentive Credit Date: to the salesmen, the date should be always 15th but month has to change...can anyone help??

```
Start Date(M/D/Year)            1/27/2017(user input)
IncentiveStart Month            4/27/2017(=EDATE(B1,3)
First Incentive Credit Date:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In B3 try...

```
=DATE(YEAR(EDATE(B2,IF(DAY(B2)>14,1,0))),MONTH(EDATE(B2,IF(DAY(B2)>14,1,0))),15)
```

Comment: thanks @Aeneas it worked. but a small change here is that. if the Date of the Month is below 15 , then incentive has to get credited in that current month. If the date is greater than 15 then it has to go next month salray. please let me know the logic

Comment: its not working. If I enter 6/27/2017 , three months from the entered date is 9/27/2017, so incentives should be credited in 10/15/2017. but as per ur formula it is giving 9/15/2017

Comment: Sorry I had the 1 and 0 around the wrong way. Have changed